# Can't run Dbeaver

Tags: dbeaver

I want to use Dbeaver, so I make a directory called `dbeaver` in `C:\` directory and then I added it to environment variables and when I run it, it shows this error :

```
!SESSION 2018-10-10 16:43:38.109 -----------------------------------------------
 eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 2 0 2018-10-10 16:43:41.855
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 [184]
Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher; bundle-version="[1.0.0,1.4.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-10-10 16:43:41.903
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException: null values not allowed
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ReferenceMap.put(ReferenceMap.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.getBundle(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:151)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:166)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

For information, I use Java 1.8.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: To simplify jre question, I think download `DBeaver with jre` would help  [Windows 64 bit (installer + JRE)](https://dbeaver.io/files/dbeaver-ce-latest-x86_64-setup.exe)